# How to do something after a time in C#?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, timer

I wanted to make a simple AI in unity that follows you and shoots BTW a certain time but I don't know how to write a code that shoots after a certain time.

Simply, The question is : How to make a Timer?

Comment: Please paste what you have tried , then you will get the answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply, there is no AI.
You can use a countdown timer (using frame count or delta time):

```cs
int timer = 10; // 10 seconds
bool stopped = false;
void Update() {
    if (timer <= 0 && !stopped) {
        // put your code here
        stopped = true;
    } else
        timer -= Time.deltaTime;
}
```

when timer stops; you can find the target direction with this code:

```cs
var heading = target.position - player.position;
var distance = heading.magnitude;
var direction = heading / distance; // This is now the normalized direction.
```

after, you can shoot in that `direction`.

Answer (score 0):

use Time.deltaTime to create a timer. Time.deltaTime gives you the time since the last frame, and by subtracting from a constant will allow you to create a timer.

```
var timeLeft = 30;

 function Update()
 {
     timeLeft -= Time.deltaTime;
     if ( timeLeft < 0 )
     {
         //function here
     }
 }
```